# can ping, but not SSH

Tags: ssh

So I have NetworkManager, connected to an AP on wlan1. I have wlan0 connected to a AdHoc network.  I have Firestarter sharing my inet on the Adhoc.

I have my ipod connected to wlan0, IP 10.42.43.101.

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:xx:12:81:7f:xx  
          inet addr:10.42.43.1  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0


wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:xx:b3:98:f2:xx 
          inet addr:10.0.1.61  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Now, I can ping my Jailbroken, SSH-enabled and running ipod touch:

```
matt: ~ $ ping 10.42.43.101
PING 10.42.43.101 (10.42.43.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.43.101: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=168 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.43.101: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=256 ms
64 bytes from 10.42.43.101: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=151 ms
^C
--- 10.42.43.101 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 151.465/191.979/256.316/46.003
```

But I cannot SSH it:

```
$ ssh root@10.42.43.101 -vv
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.42.43.101 [10.42.43.101] port 22.
```

It just stays there till I ^C it..

Here's my routing:

```
$ ip route show
10.0.1.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.61  metric 2 
10.0.1.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.61  metric 319 
169.254.0.0/16 dev vboxnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.128.223  metric 204 
10.0.0.0/8 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.42.43.1 
default via 10.0.1.1 dev wlan1  proto static 
default via 10.0.1.1 dev wlan1  metric 319
```

Comment: Did you install `openssh-server` in the target PC?

Comment: Everything looks fine on the Linux side. It sure looks like your ssh server is in fact not running on the iPod.

Answer (score 2):

I know you probably did this, but on the machine that you are trying to connect to, does netstat -a give you something like this:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.30:ssh        192.168.1.72:46480      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

At least one of the lines should show something like *:ssh for ssh connections to be established to that machine.

If not, then sshd needs to be started...

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in a comment:

> Everything looks fine on the Linux side. It sure looks like your ssh
>   server is in fact not running on the iPod.

– [Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/users/1059/gilles) [Nov 6 '11 at 15:21](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75965/can-ping-but-not-ssh#comment85969_75965)